# SQL Server 2000 Connect Timeout doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm using connect timeout in my connection string but I don't see any result

```
 Database=xxxxxx;.........pasword =xxx;connect timeout=6000;
```

Doesn't this work in SQL Server 2000?

Comment: What do you expect the `Connect Timeout` to do?? How can you tell *it's not working* - and ***how*** is it "not working" ?!?! What *result* did you expect to "see" ??

Comment: I get error timeout. in same time when i didnt use connect timeout=6000. My connection expires in same time as defaul time

Comment: I can't conceive of any circumstance where such a long timeout may be justified. A *command* timeout of that long may be, but the *connection* timeout should be based on how timely your network can be for establishing a connection. Unless you're on an RFC1149 network, this should be of the order of seconds, not nearly two hours.

Comment: 6000 its an example. Doesnt change anything if i will change it to 500. I get same error.

Comment: What error are you receiving, specifically? This timeout parameter doesn't apply to e.g. some aspects of name resolution. As soon as it's determined that the machine you're trying to connect to doesn't exist, or as soon as the machine you're trying to connect to refuses a connection, you'll get that error immediately. There's no point in the code going to sleep for a long period of time before reporting the error if it's not got some other strategy for resolving the issue itself.